# Background Image vs Reference Image - What are the pros and cons of these methods?

Tags: image

There seem to be 2 ways to add reference images in Blender as shown here https://youtu.be/PTxWKZZbIvU

Firstly you can hit Shift+a>Image>Reference, and secondly you can select a camera and in the Object Data Properties section there is "Background Images" which does the same thing. What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Also, How do you add a background image to the orthographic views?

Comment: Please prefer adding details directly here. If the linked video is not available in the future, your question will have no mean for future readers. Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While images and links are helpful additions, questions should stand on their own. [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post a link to a video](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To view through the selected camera press numpad 0.

To align the *Reference* image with the camera view, select the *Reference* image, then in the header menu > *Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation* then in the *Operator* box choose *Orientation > View*.

*Reference* and *Background* are empties, they won't be rendered, they are used as references to model an object, liked the former *Background* in 2.79.

Actually they are exactly the same objects, except that the default settings in the *Properties panel > Object Data* are not the same, by default *Background* will only be seen in orthographic view and it is set to have its back transparent (but you can switch off these 2 options or switch them on for a *Reference* image).

What's the difference? I guess it all depends on what settings make you comfortable to work with. The *Background* version works a bit more like the former *Background* in 2.79, it makes the image more discrete and transparent in your scene, and if you enable its *Only Axis Aligned* you'll see it only in perpendicular views, which is very convenient.

Answer (score 4):

*Reference* and *Background* are just two presets for an image object :)
The settings can be changed at any time through the *Properties panel.*

[image]